# Apply CSS on a div to make it optimised for all screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Hi I have been working on a web application. I have a div which contains the form inside. The code can be seen below:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:25%; width:90%;">
   <div class="col s12 m6">
     <div class="card white">
       <div class="row">

         <div class="col s12">
           <form id="example-form">
         <div>

         <h3>Site</h3>

         <section>
           <div id="mustFill">
             <label>Site Name</label>
               <input id="siteName" type="text">
           </div>

           <div id="lookup_field">
           </div>

           <label>Address Line 1</label>
```

As you can see I have applied css styling on the div here:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:25%; width:90%;">
```

I have applied the `css` to make the container appear in the center of the page to have a margin from the left and specific width in `%`. 
I initially had it in exact `px` like `margin left:400px; width:800px` which made the page look awful on different screen sizes such as iPads, Mobiles, Smaller Screen laptops etc.

However applying `CSS` in `%` still has the same problem. How can I apply `CSS` to this div that it is optimised for all screen sizes and does not look awful.

Comment: If you want a block-level element to appear in the middle of the screen, use `margin: 0 auto` after specifying a width. I'd also suggest you look in to using CSS Media Queries, if you're concerned about making your page work at multiple resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can be more precise by using the calc function

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:2em; width:calc(100%-4em);">
```

which means you have a margin on the left of 2 letter width, and you apply a total width of 100% - 4 letter widths

I recommend you use all styling in class="row" instead of style, this will allow you to have different styles on different devices by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
.row {
  margin-left:2em; 
  width:calc(100%-4em);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .row {
      margin-left:1em; 
      width:calc(100%-2em);
    }
}
```